# How to restrict installing ios app from appstore for some of the devices which doesn't support NFC?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, passkit

I have been working on NFC based passes iOS App where some some of the devices doesn't support NFC. How to restrict that devices from installing the apps from appstore?

Where the OS is supported but the hardware doesn't support for NFC enabled passes(Apple VAS Protocol not CoreNFC).

Is there any settings needs to be done in Xcode for NFC pass enabled device only to support?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run your app only for NFC supported models then you need to add UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in Info.plist:

```
key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    // ... your restrictions
    <string>nfc</string>
</array>
```

With this requirement only the devices with NFC will be able to download our app from App Store.

Sources:

1. [Device Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html)
2. [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uirequireddevicecapabilities)

Comment: It is Can be restricted to enable for Core NFC Supporting Device but what i need is to NFC Enabled passes supported devices There is difference between Core NFC and Apple VAS NFC support.

Answer (score -2):

You can't restrict device models to install app. You can only use deployment target, to restrict by iOS version. That's only way to make some restrictions.